# Target an ID with jQuery that I only know the beginning to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, target

Is it possible to target IDs that begin with 'category_id_' and after that there are 3 digits.
But I want to target all IDs that only begin with 'category_id_'.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, use the attribute starts with selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) with wild card

```
$('[id^=category_id_]');
```

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a
>   value beginning exactly with a given string, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

To bind event

```
$(document).on ("click", "[id^=category_id_]", function () {
```

Comment: How would it replace this:

$(document).on ("click", "#category_id_333", function () {

Comment: @ClaudioDelgado, use `$(document).on ("click", "[id^=category_id_]", function () {})`

Comment: That's awesome! It took me a while to integrate everything into my code but I just did it and it works superb. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

That would be the attribute starts with selector :

```
$('[id^="category_id_"]')
```

and to be even more specific you can use a filter:

```
$('[id^="category_id_"]').filter(function() {
    var str = this.id.replace('category_id_','');

    if(str.length === 3) {
       // there where 3 more characters 

       str.replace(/\D/,'').length === 3 // they where all numbers
    }
}).something();
```